# Avalonia change ListBox ItemPanel to Wrap in code without XAML

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm using `Avalonia.Desktop` version `0.10.18`.  I've created a library to create simple UI with code only and I'm using Avalonia to generate the UI.

I'm wanting to find out why the following code causes an exception.

```cs
var itemsCtrl = new ListBox();

itemsCtrl.ItemsPanel = new ItemsPanelTemplate
{
    Content = new WrapPanel()
};
```

That code causes this exception:

```
Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (templateContent)
 ---> System.ArgumentException: templateContent
   at Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.Templates.TemplateContent.Load(Object templateContent) in /_/src/Markup/Avalonia.Markup.Xaml/Templates/TemplateContent.cs:line 22
   at Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.Templates.ItemsPanelTemplate.Build() in /_/src/Markup/Avalonia.Markup.Xaml/Templates/ItemsPanelTemplate.cs:line 13
   at Avalonia.Controls.Presenters.ItemsPresenterBase.CreatePanel() in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Presenters/ItemsPresenterBase.cs:line 238
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 554
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Controls.Presenters.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Presenters/ScrollContentPresenter.cs:line 254
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 559
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Grid.cs:line 1149
   at Avalonia.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Grid.cs:line 1005
   at Avalonia.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Grid.cs:line 489
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 559
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 625
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 559
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Layout.LayoutHelper.MeasureChild(ILayoutable control, Size availableSize, Thickness padding) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/LayoutHelper.cs:line 46
   at Avalonia.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Border.cs:line 187
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 559
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 625
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 559
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Grid.cs:line 1149
   at Avalonia.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Grid.cs:line 1005
   at Avalonia.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Grid.cs:line 489
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 559
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Layout.LayoutHelper.MeasureChild(ILayoutable control, Size availableSize, Thickness padding) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/LayoutHelper.cs:line 46
   at Avalonia.Controls.Presenters.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Presenters/ContentPresenter.cs:line 366
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 559
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Layout.LayoutHelper.MeasureChild(ILayoutable control, Size availableSize, Thickness padding) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/LayoutHelper.cs:line 46
   at Avalonia.Controls.Primitives.VisualLayerManager.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Primitives/VisualLayerManager.cs:line 133
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 559
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 625
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 559
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 625
   at Avalonia.Controls.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Window.cs:line 916
   at Avalonia.Controls.WindowBase.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/WindowBase.cs:line 247
   at Avalonia.Layout.Layoutable.Measure(Size availableSize) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable.cs:line 364
   at Avalonia.Layout.LayoutManager.Measure(ILayoutable control) in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/LayoutManager.cs:line 297
   at Avalonia.Layout.LayoutManager.ExecuteInitialLayoutPass() in /_/src/Avalonia.Layout/LayoutManager.cs:line 184
   at Avalonia.Controls.Window.ShowCore(Window parent) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Window.cs:line 693
```

However if I create the ListBox using the XAML parser it does not throw an exception, and works as expected.  I use this code [here](https://github.com/NathanielACollier/dotnetLib_nac.Forms/blob/master/nac.Forms/Form.Collections.cs)

```cs
var itemsCtrl = Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.AvaloniaRuntimeXamlLoader.Parse<ListBox>($@"
    <ListBox {lib.Util.writeXAMLNS()}
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=""Disabled""
            >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
", localAssembly: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Form)));
```

I'm wanting to know if there is a way to set the ListBox to use a WrapPanel in code only without xaml.

Comment: See if this helps : https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/98

Answer (score 0):

I also asked on the [Avalonia discussion area of github](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/11765#discussioncomment-6168061), and got a great answer.  I changed the code to this, and it works.

```cs
itemsCtrl.ItemsPanel = new FuncTemplate<IPanel>(() => new WrapPanel());
```